# Truth tables in python?

Tags: python, sympy, boolean-logic, truthtable

I am working in Python, and I would like to manipulate data in the form of truth tables. I need to simplify tables, translate tables to boolean expressions, etc... I discovered `sympy`, but it doesn't seem to provide native support for truth tables. I also found some other utilities, such as `pyeda`, but before diving into one of them I would like to know if there is any commonly accepted standard package to do what I need.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really depends on what exactly you are working with. In general though, any kind of "... table" should be a ``dict`` unless there is a reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating truth tables from a boolean expression is not that difficult
with `sympy`.

In the program below, the boolean expression is used to generate
the list of models that are satisfiable. Using a generator for
all possible variable truth combinations, it lists the complete
truth table.

```
import itertools
from sympy import *
from sympy.logic import simplify_logic
from sympy.logic.inference import satisfiable

my_names = 'ABCD'
A,B,C,D = symbols(','.join(my_names))
e1 = Nor(Nor(A, B), Or(C, D))
my_symbols = sorted(e1.atoms(Symbol), key=lambda x: x.name)
print('Set of symbols used:', my_symbols)
models = satisfiable(e1, all_models=True)
sat_mods = []
for m in models:
    sat_mods.append(dict(sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].name)))
truth_tab = []
for c in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=len(my_symbols)):
    model = dict(zip(my_symbols, c))
    truth_tab.append((model, model in sat_mods))
print(truth_tab)
```

Output:

```
# Set of symbols used: [A, B, C, D]
# [({A: True, B: True, C: True, D: True}, False),
#  ({A: True, B: True, C: True, D: False}, False),
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a library for creating truth tables from boolean expressions: https://github.com/salt-die/truth_tables.

Example usage:

```py
>>> from truth_tables import TruthTable
>>> my_table = TruthTable('p or q', '~p -> q', 'T and ~T')
>>> print(my_table)
┌───┬───┬────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ p │ q │ p or q │ ~p -> q │ T and ~T │
├───┼───┼────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ F │ F │   F    │    F    │    F     │
│ F │ T │   T    │    T    │    F     │
│ T │ F │   T    │    T    │    F     │
│ T │ T │   T    │    T    │    F     │
└───┴───┴────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
>>> print(my_table.ast)
Or
├─Var('p')
╰─Var('q')

Implies
├─Negate
│ ╰─Var('p')
╰─Var('q')

And
├─Const(True)
╰─Negate
  ╰─Const(True)
```